# How to display data into a fragment after being implemented

Tags: android

I’m trying to pass some data into a fragment but I can't display it correctly. First of all i implement the fragment into the activity like this:

```
View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header_fragement, null);
```

In this step the activity get the initial status of the fragment (blank). But from another activity I pass some data to this fragment this way.

```
 infos = new Bundle();

 infos.putString("Id",jObj.getString("ID"));
 infos.putString("Name",jObj.getString("display_name"));
 infos.putString("ImgUrl","http://unchained-network.com/uploads/profilpics/53f5c570b6ac2.png");

 HeaderFragement hf = new HeaderFragement();

 hf.init(infos);
```

Data which i can't display it into the fragment : normaly i do this

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }*/

    // fields in which I put my values
    name = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nameH);
    img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageViewHeader);
```

And this

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //Trying to set the values.
    name.setText(infos.getString("Name"));
    img.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(infos.getString("ImgUrl")));

}
```

and Image to illustrate the problem

[image: Image to illustrate the problem]

I know that the activity get the Layout and not the instanced Fragment, but I’m trying to find a way to display the data anyway.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

init your views in **onCreateView()** method.